# I am attempting to add a background image to my vue.js project

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-material

I want to add a background image that covers the whole page. However this is how it looks now :

[image: This is the image]

I want it to span the whole web page. How would this be done in vue.js?

I also want an animated toolbar so that when the page is not scrolling the toolbar is transparent and takes the look of the background image. When it scrolls the toolbar will have the current blue color

Here is my fiddle

[vue.js project](http://jsfiddle.net/mxx3d7ob/7/)

THIS is the HTML

```
<template>
  <div id = "background">

            <div class = "" id = "explain">

                   <h1 class = "md-title">{{ message }}</h1>

                   <h3> Collect, analyse  and do better with data!</h3>

            </div>
<hr>
<md-layout id = "container">

            <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">

    <span class="md-headline">HOW does levi function ?</span>
            </md-layout>


<md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
  <h3>levi uses research and experimentation to provide
  'actionable knowledge' that you can use to <b>do well </b>in your environment. </h3>
</md-layout>

                  <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large = "33" md-flex-xlarge = "33">
                    <h4>  Identify and Collect what is needed</h4>
                  </md-layout>
                  <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large = "33" md-flex-xlarge = "33">
                      <h4> Organize and analyse the evidence</h4>
                  </md-layout>
                  <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="33" md-flex-large = "33" md-flex-xlarge = "33">
                      <h4>Communicate and act on the evidence! </h4>
                  </md-layout>


</md-layout>



<md-layout id = "Identity">

      <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
      <span class="md-headline"> HOW do we exist?</span>
      </md-layout>

      <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
          Our team realized that many institutions are unable to deconstruct their environment and respond to its need because; they do not have the
cost effective products, proper processes , and the necessary execution techniques required to do so.
<p>levi has been built to provide the platform and process necessary to help those in need <b>do well.</b></p>
      </md-layout>



           <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
              <span class="md-headline">WHAT do we do?</span>
          </md-layout>

          <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
            Our community combines products and processes to augment human intelligence, reduce waste, and provide wellbeing.
         </md-layout>

         <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">
        <span class="md-headline"></span>
        </md-layout>

        <md-layout md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="100" md-flex-large="100" md-flex-xlarge="100">

       </md-layout>

</md-layout>

  </div>

</template>
```

THIS is the CSS

```
<style scoped>

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 49px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  font-family: Heiti SC;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 19px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Helvetica neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
}

#Identity > .md-layout {
  /*background-color: lightgrey;*/
  border-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*border-style: dotted;*/
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

span {
  font-family: Helvetica neue;
}
```

THIS is the css syntax for rendering the background.

> ```
>  #background {
>       background: url(../../assets/whiteCoffeedarken.jpg);
>     }
> ```

```
#container > .md-layout {
  /*background-color: lightgrey;*/
  border-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*border-style: dotted;*/
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
}


</style>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 9):

*I do not agree with the comments. This is actually a true question about Vue.js.* :)

You are using single file components, so I suppose you created your project with **vue-cli** and the **webpack** template...

If you open your [Vue.js devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools), you can inspect your components. This is particularly handy to determine their visual limits.

All components, including `App.vue`, are injected into your `index.html` and have, to some extent, an independent existence. So if you want to set a full background image for the body, not just for a specific component inside of it, you have two main options:

1. Create a static stylesheet
2. Put your style rules in `App.vue`

---

## Static stylesheet

Create a `style.css` file and put it in the `static` folder. Here, it will not be processed by Webpack. In this file, you could have the following code:

```
body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
}
```

Open your `index.html` and include your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
```

## Style rules in `App.vue`

With this solution, you can put the following code in the style section of `App.vue`:

```
body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
}
```

**However, you have to remove the `scoped` attribute!**

The explanation is in the [vue-loader documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html):

> When a  tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What I want to do is create the background image for my 'Homepage' component and nothing else. 
_I should have specify that initially._ 

Is the process the same?

Comment: This is indeed a key information that should appear in your question... I do not think the process will be the same in your case, especially if you plan to create an SPA with vue-router. But generally speaking, when you want to style a specific component in Vue, it is better to write your CSS rules in its `.vue` file...

Comment: What you have provided has actually help me significantly in furthering my understanding of vue.js. 

I actually have placed the css background inside that specific component. The issue is that it spans only parts of the layout and not the whole page as shown in the above image. The element with the _background id_ contains the image speficied in the CSS declaration.

Comment: Wasted a lot of time before finding this straight-forward answer. Thank you