# vue cli global body style not included in build

Tags: vue.js, build, scope, styles

I added this css rule

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: rgb(184, 182, 182);
}

#app {
...
</style>
```

to my **App.vue** file within the  tag (not scoped ;-); as learned in [vue mastery courses](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses). Which BTW are a great help!

This approach also is proposed by [Babacadabra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910253/badacadabra) in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572731/i-am-attempting-to-add-a-background-image-to-my-vue-js-project).

Everything builds fine, and the locally defined (scoped) styles of a component can be found in the dist/css folder.
But my global  style declaration for the background-color disappeared. As result the website layout is different than the one I tested locally (using 'vue serve'):

**The background color is not applied.**

What am I making wrong?

I helped myself by adding the background-color declaration directly to my index file, but that should be a patch only. I'm looking for a final solution, so the complete workflow works as expected and local and remote versions behave the same.

UPDATE (more code):
As requested here more details, i.e. the complete App.vue. I hope that is sufficient, since to my (very basic ;.-) understanding of vue the global style declarations go into this Module.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img class="vservuLogo" alt="VservuLogo" src="./assets/VservU-Logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to VservU GmbH Munich"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background-color: rgb(184, 182, 182);
}

#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.vservuLogo {
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

UPDATE2:

Since I could not reproduce that behavior in a new project, I guess **I simply missed to clear the cache!**

Comment: please add more code snippet to be more clear

Comment: What else do you need?
I don't think the complete App.vue does unveil more needed details, but here you go:

Comment: Oops, I was to slow and could no more edit my comment, that's the reason of this next comment; sorry!

I added the complete App.vue to my original question. The comment does not offer enough space ;-)

Comment: i will try it out

Comment: it works fine on my code and the given background-color is applied

Comment: strange... Do you have any idea what could go wrong on my side?
You can check it out; the website is available onsite :
https://vservu.megazine3.de

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179420/discussion-between-boussadjra-and-hnuecke).

Comment: OK... Just to share my actual findings:

I setup a completely new project and only added the background-color to body... And it worked!
I also found that style declaration in the obviously combined css file.
My obviously incorrect assumption was, that this css file only contained the scoped declarations; what was wrong: It contains everything!
The selectors of the scoped ones contain specific attribute selectors like:

[data-v-216abc19]

Lessons learned ;-)

I do not know what went wrong, Actually, it looks like everything is working as expected.
Sorry for keeping you busy!

Comment: no problem, you are welcome